# How to get all available event log name?

Tags: c++, windows, events, logging

Is there a SDK function that can get all available event log names in the local computer? With OpenEventLog function, I must know the event log name beforehand. Under Windows XP system, there is three default event log called Application, Security, and System. But in recent operating systems, it seems there are more logs and user can define his own log. In such a case, how to get a list of the logs in the local computer via C++?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate subkeys of `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog` in the system registry.
PS: There was a possibility to add custom event log even in Windows 2000.